# Window Focus Disable in Android

Tags: android

I am stuck in a scenario. I have a login Form. I want to show it as disabled for some users. I can get that users but I dont know how to remove the focus from the window.

```
//to check whether the current user is administrator or not
    public void checkAdministrator(){

        String owner = ParseValues.parsedGroupList.get(indexofGroup).getGroup_owner();
        String currentUser = CCMStaticVariable.loginUserId+"@abc.com";

        if(owner.equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser)){
            administrator=true;
        }
        else{
            administrator=false;
        }
    }
```

Now -

```
if(!administrator){

//here I want to disable the whole Activity, I just want to show the activity in disabled state


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your parent layout from your login xml and try this

```
parentLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: just create methods for enabling and disabling the views you would like to make change and call particular method according to the situation.

Comment: I have just simply checked your method without any condition , just to check if it works or not.. but it failed